# What does 即便確實發生了什麼事，也不會波及到你身上 say?

Tags: translation

> 即便確實發生了什麼事，也不會波及到你身上。

I believe this is in traditional.  The English text is:

> Even if something does happen, nothing will happen to you.

I don’t think I translated this correct, can anyone tell me what it says?  Please give a detailed answer.

Comment: what is the  English text you translated from? Or what do you translate this Chinese text to?

Comment: English text is - Even if something does happen, nothing will happen to you.  Thank you for your help, your answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

即便 = even if

確實 = actually

發生了 = happened

什麼 = what

事 = matter

也 = still

不會 = wouldn't

波及 = spread/involve

到 ~ 上 = onto ~

到你身上 = onto you personally

> 即便確實發生了什麼事，也不會波及到你身上。
>
> Even if anything actually happened, it still wouldn't involve you personally